# Hide error text until box / button clicked on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm wanting the errName errEmail errMessage text to not be displayed until the user clicks on the Name, Email, or Message box. Also I'm wanting to not show $result until the submit button is pressed. As of right now it just displays the errName, errEmail, errMessage, and the alert even if the user is not interacting with the submit form.

````php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
global $result;
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $errName ="";
    $errEmail ="";
    $errMessage ="";
    $result="";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $business = $_POST['business'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = '------';
    $to = '-----';
    $subject = 'Message from user on website';
    $body ="-------";
}
// Check if name has been entered
if (!isset($_POST) || !key_exists('name', $_POST) || !filter_var($_POST['name'])) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}
// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!isset($_POST) || !key_exists('email', $_POST) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
//Check if message has been entered
if (!isset($_POST) || !key_exists('message', $_POST) || !filter_var($_POST['message'])) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!isset($errName) && !isset($errEmail) && !isset($errMessage)) {
    $result .= '<br><div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch</div>';
} else {
    $result .= '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
}


  <div class="container" id="contact">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="page-header text-center">Email Form</h1>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php#contact">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php showPost('name'); ?>">
                            <?php if (isset($errName)) {
                  echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";
                }?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="business" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Business</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="business" name="business" placeholder="Business name" value="<?php showPost('business'); ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php showPost('email'); ?>">
                            <?php if (isset($errEmail)) {
                  echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";
                }?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php showPost('message');?></textarea>
                            <?php if (isset($errMessage)) {
                  echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";
                }?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="form-group text-xs-center">
              <div style="margin: 0 auto" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="----------"></div>
            </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>```
````

Comment: for a pic of the errors here is an Imgur link https://imgur.com/a/Fpzfb1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all your php code inside `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))` ,because the condition `!isset` will always be true when you `load` your php page . Do below change in your code :

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $errName ="";
    $errEmail ="";
    $errMessage ="";
    $result="";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $business = $_POST['business'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = '------';
    $to = '-----';
    $subject = 'Message from user on website';
    $body ="-------";

// Check if name has been entered
if (!isset($_POST) || !key_exists('name', $_POST) || !filter_var($_POST['name'])) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}
// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!isset($_POST) || !key_exists('email', $_POST) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
//Check if message has been entered
if (!isset($_POST) || !key_exists('message', $_POST) || !filter_var($_POST['message'])) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!isset($errName) && !isset($errEmail) && !isset($errMessage)) {
    $result .= '<br><div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch</div>';
} else {
    $result .= '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
}
} // end of isset
```